# Where does DesktopAppConverter.exe located in system downloaded from WindowsStore?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, dac

I had installed Desktop App Converter from Windows Store using below url -
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/desktop-app-converter/9nblggh4skzw

Ideally when app gets installed, its corresponding executable Should be present on system. But I am unable to find DesktopAppConverter.exe path in System.

I tried to find it on below path: 
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages

But it won't help.

Regards,
Ankush

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to find it on below path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
>   C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages

To access the `WindowsApps` folder, you may need to acquire permission. Have you done that? After installing the Desktop App Converter, I can find the DesktopAppConverter.exe under the path:
[image]

And under this path in `C:` I can also find the exe:
[image]

If you just use this tool to convert desktop app, you can directly launch it from start menu. Or you can also use PowerShell to run the tool to convert app after installing the tool from Store.

Actually, you can also use [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) package an existing Win32 app which also enables Store publishing or sideloading.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew stated, you can launch the DAC directly from the Start menu if you search for 'Desktop App Converter':

[image]

The executable and PowerShell script can be found at 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.0.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\'
(**assuming you are using version 2.0.2.0**)